# How to test my iphone app in my iphone, instead of the simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator

How to test my iphone app in my iphone, instead of the simulator?

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in the [iPhone Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).

Comment: So, I will have to pay 100$ even to test it on my own device?

Comment: This is [the new link](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) to the iOS development guide.

Answer (score 2):

Yes to test it on your own device you will need to pay the $100 to grab the certificate, unless your device is jailbroken.

Comment: Thanks. Feel like hurling curses at Apple so much, but I desist since this is not the place to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There are some steps you need to follow to test your app on your personal iPhone. Below you can find all the steps:

1. Create MAC certificate at first step.
2. Second step is to upload that certificate to developer account.
3. Now you should open developer account at http://www.developer.apple.com
4. You can now find an option for device id in your developer account on left side.
5. Now you should register your iPhone device.
6. It is time to create your unique identifier on developer account
7. download your certificate and install it on xcode organize
8. Now open your project embed your unique identifier in your project.

Comment: The link is now broken, apple uses https.  [This is the new link](https://developer.apple.com/)